# Multiple curl calls php issue

Tags: amazon-web-services

My problem every 20minutes I want to execute the curl request which is around 25000 or more than that and save the curl response in database. In PHP it is not handled properly which is the best AWS services I can use except lambda.

Comment: Sorry, what is your question? And what do you mean by "execute the curl request which is around 25000 or more than that"? What do you mean by "not handled properly"? Please Edit your question to add more details.

Comment: @john Rotenstien My scenario is every 20 minutes my cron is running in that cron i am taking the ids from the database which has entries more than 25000 now which will increases.I am taking all the records from the db and one by one i am fetching the data from the third party using curl call and need to save in the database what is the best approach for that? It is helpful if you suggests something

Comment: What is your main problem at the moment? Is the process taking too long? Are you having difficulties writing to the database? Are you wanting a better way to orchestrate this process in some way? Why do you say "except lambda"?

Comment: Because of calling curl sometime my process is interrupted or break in between in PHP that's why i want to execute the code in another way.

Answer (score 1):

A common technique for processing large number of similar calls is:

- Create an **Amazon Simple Queue Service (SQS) queue** and push each request into the queue as a separate message. In your case, the message would contain the URL that you wish to retrieve.
- Create an **AWS Lambda function** that performs the download and stores the data in the database.
- Configure the Lambda function to **trigger off the SQS queue**

This way, the SQS queue can **trigger hundreds of Lambda functions running parallel**. The default concurrency limit is 1000 Lambda functions, but you can request for this to be increased.

You would then need a separate process that, every 20 minutes, queries the database for the URLs and pushes the messages into the SQS queue.

The complete process is:

```
Schedule -> Lambda pusher -> messages into SQS -> Lambda workers -> database
```

The beauty of this design is that it can scale to **handle large workloads and operates in parallel**, rather than each `curl` request having to wait. If a message cannot be processed, it Lambda will automatically try again. Repeated failures will send the message to a [Dead Letter Queue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-dead-letter-queues.html) for later analysis and reprocessing.

If you wish to perform **25,000 queries every 20 minutes** (1200 seconds), this would need a query to complete every 0.05 seconds. That's why it is important to work in parallel.

By the way, if you are attempting to scrape this information from a single website, I suggest you investigate whether they provide an API otherwise you might be violating the Terms & Conditions of the website, which I strongly advise against.